# Hide property in swagger request but show in swagger response

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have one dto class which is used in the other class, lets say it looks like this:

```
class Foo {
private String id;
private String name;
}

class Bar {
private String id;
private Foo foo;
}
```

Both foo and bar have their own controllers with POST and GET methods.

Bar POST request looks like this:

```
{"id":bar1, "foo": { "id": "foo1"}}
```

so the only required field from foo is id, but the response contains all Foo parameters. Also when posting Foo I need to provide each parameter and in response I'm also receiving all params.

But now in swagger for POST /bar controller I want to show only required field from Foo - the id.

Is it possible to hide other params and show only id in POST /bar request swagger without hidding them in Foo's requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 Foo classes and 2 Bar classes as follows::

```
class FooReq { // used in request
    private String id;
}

class FooResp extends FooReq { // used in response
    private String name;
}

class BarReq {
    private String id;
    private FooReq foo;
}
class BarResp {
    private String id;
    private FooResp foo;
}
```

Controller method def:

```
public ResponseEntity<BarResp> postBar(@RequestBody BarReq postBody)
```

Comment: Okay, and there are no other options to do it with only one Foo class?

Comment: I believe not. There is no annotation or suchlike that sometimes hides fields. You need two classes. Fortunately, inheritance helps a bit, at least to keep things clean.